# Работа с Awesome.NET без UI компонента и с многопоточностью

Tags: c#, многопоточность, webview, события, awesomium

У меня есть кое-какое решение и вопрос. Перерыл весь инет, пережил бессонную неделю(ну, почти :), но все же я нашел решение. Собственно вот и оно:

Создаем поток, который будет в полной власти у WebCore Awesomium'а(с этим-то и проблемы потом будут):

```
    Thread awesomiumThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            WebCore.Started += (s, crStr) =>
            {
                awesomiumContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            };
            WebCore.Run();
        }));
        awesomiumThread.Start();
        WebCore.Initialize(WebConfig.Default);
```

`SynchronizationContext awesomiumContext` у нас тут - это удивительная штука, граничащая с магией(для меня, по крайней мере :). Создает контекст потока, с помощью которого потом можно в него ворваться в любой момент(более подробно ищите в интернетах).

А `WebCore.Run()` резервирует(блокирует) поток, в котором был запущен, вплоть до вызова `WebCore.Shutdown()`.

После это процедуры можно теперь вызвать любой метод в потоке Awesomium вот такой командой: `awesomiumContext.Post(Method, Params);` или `awesomiumContext.Send(Method, Params)`.

Теперь самая главная загвоздка и собственно моя текущая проблема. В потоке WebCore не происходит автоматического обновления(в привычном понимании), зато есть возможность использовать event'ы, такие как `DocumentReady` или `LoadingFrameComplete`. Но есть большое но. Дождаться обновления в потоке не получится, т.к. любая работа в нем блокирует этот самый поток и дождаться срабатывания event'а не выйдет. Вот и пришлось мне немаленький код разбрасывать по мелким кусочкам, бросая бедный браузер из основного потока в обработчик, потом в другой поток и обратно по кругу, пытаясь выловить срабатывание обработчика событий. Так что буду невероятно благодарен, если у кого-то будет рабочий способ дожидаться загрузки страницы в Awesomium без пинг-понга WebViewer'ом.

Comment: `WebCore.Update()`, кстати, можно вызывать вручную.

Comment: Это было мое первое решение, но с этим подходом не работает многопоточность, приложение просто падает, без Exception, как подкошенное.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте асинхронное программирование и класс TaskCompletionSource. Систему событий Awesomium я не знаю, поэтому напишу решение в общем виде, точные названия событий подставите сами.

```
public Task<EventArgs> WaitForSomeEvent(CancellationToken token) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EventArgs>();
    var registration = token.Register(() => ctx.TrySetCanceled());
    EventHandler handler = e => ctx.TrySetResult(e);
    someObject.SomeEvent += handler;
    tcs.Task.ContinuewWith(_ => { 
        someObject.SomeEvent -= handler;
        registration.Dispose();
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Что тут происходит? Мы создаем `TaskCompletionSource`, вешаем три обработчика событий и выходим, вернув вызывающему коду задачу для ожидания. Далее события могут развиваться по одному из двух сценариев.

Сценарий первый - срабатывает `someObject.SomeEvent`. Тогда мы переводим `TaskCompletionSource` в состояние "выполнено", передав параметр события в качетве результата работы.

Сценарий второй - ожидание было отменено. Тогда мы отменяем `TaskCompletionSource`.

Независимо от сценария, далее срабатывает третий обработчик, который я повесил на саму возвращаемую задачу - он подчищает ресурсы, снимая первые два обработчика (третий снимать не нужно - он однократный).

Как эту радость использовать? Очень просто:

```
public async void Foo() {
   ... // делаем что-нибудь нужное
   await WaitForSomeEvent(CancellationToken.None); // Для простоты я никогда не отменяю ожидание
   ... // делаем что-нибудь еще
}
```

Что произойдет в этом коде? Сначала будет выполнен блок кода до оператора `await`. Потом метод `WaitForSomeEvent` подпишется на событие `SomeEvent` и вернет задачу. Далее оператор `await` увидит, что задача еще не выполнена, запомнит текущий контекст выполнения, подпишется на задачу - и вернет управление из метода (да, управление из асинхронных методов возвращается на первом же операторе `await`).

После того, как задача перейдет в любое из "завершенных" состояний (в данном случае она может перейти только в состояние "выполнена" - поскольку мы никогда ее не отменяем), обработчик оператора `await` достанет сохраненный контекст синхронизации и запланирует в нем продолжение работы метода.

Таким образом, асинхронное программирование, хотя и не уберет "прыжки" по потокам в рантайме - но определенно поможет навести порядок в вашем коде, склеив мелкие кусочки обратно в асинхронный метод.

Comment: Я сегодня уже не протестирую, но завтра посмотрю обязательно. Эх, сколько мне всего еще учить :D

Comment: Можно еще чуть подробнее? Просто awesomium устроен так, что поток, в котором он выполняется, никогда не остановится сам (разве что в случае краха), следовательно await WaitForSomeEvent(CancellationToken.None); просто зависнет.

Comment: @iRumba с чего вы взяли, что `await WaitForSomeEvent(CancellationToken.None);` хоть как-то связан со временем жизни потока?

Comment: Ни с чего, просто предположил. Сейчас затачиваю это под свою задачу, там и проверю